# Twitter Bootstrap Active Navigation Link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set my navigation link to active when I pressed it and stay active, and It works fine but when I apply this jQuery script I can't open any links to other .html pages. This is my markup:

```
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
```

... and my jQuery:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');                
        });            
    });
    </script>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you need e.preventDefault() ? My guess would be it's preventing the navigation!

Comment: Thank you :). Deleted it and everything works fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you prevent link default click behavior (open page).

Try that way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.nav > li a').click(function (e) {
            $(this).closest('ul.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');                
        });            
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, YD1m, this one works too. I just needed to delete e.preventDefault()  :)

Comment: Ok, bounds of `a` and `li` elements can be differ. In my sample you handle only clicks on `a` as standart practice. If you want to handle clicks on `li` element you can change it `cursor` attribute style to show for users that `li` is clickable :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
$(function () {

       $(document).on('click', '.ul.nav li', function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.siblings('li').removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');

            return false;
        });

}
```